# Transform xml using xsl in c# displays empty file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt

I am trying to transform an xml file using an xsl file and open the the transformed xml file in a new window. I am fetching xml and xsl file from sql server database as strings , convert them into xml documents and then transforming the xml file using xsl, Below is my code

```
IQueryable<DataDictionaryReport> reportsQuery = from d in dataDictionaryContext.DataDictionaryReports
                                                         where d.DBID == j
                                                         select d;
        string displayXML=null ;
        string displayXSL=null;

        foreach (var report in reportsQuery)
        {
            displayXML = report.ReportXML;
            displayXSL = report.ReportXSL;
        }

        //myLabel.Text = displayXML;

        XmlDocument docXML = new XmlDocument();
        docXML.LoadXml(displayXML);
        XmlTextWriter writerXML = new XmlTextWriter(Server.MapPath("/document/Model Report.xml"), null);
        writerXML.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        docXML.Save(writerXML);

        XmlDocument docXSL= new XmlDocument();
        docXSL.LoadXml(displayXSL);
        XmlTextWriter writerXSL = new XmlTextWriter(Server.MapPath("/document/Model Report.xsl"), null);
        writerXSL.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        docXSL.Save(writerXSL);

try
{
  XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(Server.MapPath("/document/output.xml"), null);
  XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
  xslt.Load("/document/Model Report.xsl");
  xslt.Transform("/document/Model Report.xml", "/document/output.xml"); 
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
   Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
  }

 string newWin = "window.open('" + "/document/output.xml" + "');";
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "pop", newWin, true);
```

My output.xml displays an empty file. I am posting the first few lines of code for the xsl file, probably its too long,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:key name="IDs" match="*" use="@id" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
           <head>
              <title>Table/Columns Report</title>
              <script type="text/javascript">
               // <![CDATA[
               function toggle(element, togimg) {
                  if (element.style.display == 'none') {
                      element.style.display = 'block';
                      togimg.src="images/collapse.gif";
                  }
                  else {
                      element.style.display = 'none';
                      togimg.src="images/expand.gif";
                  }
               }
               // ]]></script>
            </head>
            ...
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: An empty file is not the same as an error. Perhaps this behaviour is to be expected because of the XSLT stylesheet you apply. Can you show it?

Comment: Oops the xsl file is too long, it cant be pasted here

Comment: Never post code in a comment - edit your question instead.

Comment: Have you tried to test your XSL transformation in a first time? I mean, maybe the transformation yields an empty file.

Comment: Yes I have tried the xsl transform in the first time, works just absolutely fine , here just that i am fetching xml and xsl file from sql server database

Comment: You have edited your post now, but you are not showing an XSLT stylesheet, I'm afraid. This is an arbitrary XML with only comment nodes in it. A stylesheet starts with the root `xsl:stylesheet` and its usual file extension is `*.xsl` - try to find it.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I have added only the first few lined of the xsl file, since its too long.

Comment: If the XSL is too big to include, try breaking it down into smaller chunks and create a [short self-contained example](http://sscce.org). The process of doing so might make the error more apparent to yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It displayed an empty file, the error was resolved by streaming the XML document to memory and  then reading from memory. The code is as below,

```
MemoryStream stm = new MemoryStream();
xslt.Transform(docXML, null, stm);

stm.Position = 1;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stm);
Response.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
```